# Can I start parallel pipelines from a for loop in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use parallel stages starting pipelines however I need a for loop to define some of the parameters for pipelines. How should I do that? Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for somethibng like below?

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Parallel') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelJobs()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def accounts() {
  return ["dynamic", "list"]
}

def parallelJobs() {
  jobs = [:]

  for (account in accounts()) {
    jobs[account] = { stage(account) {
       echo "Step for $account"
     }
    }
  }
  return jobs
}
```